# jsch thinks it's missing a class

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ant, jsch

I am getting a "Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger" when trying to use jsch with Ant in Eclipse under Ubuntu.

Both jar and the Eclipse project explorer claim that the class is present in the jar file.

My Googling on the issue says corrupted jar file is the likely cause but that does not seem to be the issue here.

Does this error message show up if there are other errors in using jsch?

Comment: What is the version of the jar file you  are using ? have you tred [this](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/java-programming/could-not-load-a-dependent-class-comjcraftjschlogger/)?

Comment: I have tried several versions.  The one that came with the Eclipse install, the one from the OpenJDK7 install, from the jsch site.  The situation described in your link could be diagnosed by errors from the jar utility. There are no errors from that utility in my case.  My current (and somewhat magical) thinking is that Eclipse is using a fixed version buried somewhere and configuration has no effect.  Either that or Logging is broken in jsch and it throws that error if it finds any other errors.  Has anyone got useful errors out of jsch?